# How to keep two divs a fixed width from each other and centered?

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at this jsfiddle right away to get a grasp on what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/w7yayb5e/

Basically in this mockup I have a circle and rectangle styled in css and positioned absolutely on a background that is supposed to be 100% **height** (couldn't get that to work in jsfiddle).

HTML:

```
<section class="background">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class ="rectangle"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
    background: #666;
    height: 275px;
    width: 100%;
}

.circle {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fafafa;
    margin: 0 auto 40px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)
}

.rectangle {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    top: 26.5%;
}
```

Now to the problem: as I stretch the window bigger horizontally, the two objects glide from each other, soon reaching the point where things would look weird on a real page. The reverse situation, where the window is made smaller and the two objects glide into each other, is dealt with responsively, changing the layout completely on that screen size.

**I would like the two objects to stay a fixed width from each other, while being centered together on the page.**

I am aware that this might be impossible without changing the absolute positioning, and even though I would like to retain the vertical positioning I guess I will accept any solution at this point and scrap the 100% height design. I've pored through perhaps 10 different questions that seem to be about the same thing here, yet none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w7yayb5e/2/) works for you?

Comment: @vbarbarosh Ah, it might, although not exactly centered but close enough maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap both shapes into a container and since the shapes has fixed sizes it's easy to calculate the height and width of this container (in your example 344x104).

then you just have to position the container in the center of your background using:

```
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
```

and the shapes don't need an absolute position and just a float to keep them same line.

Hope this is clear enough. here you have a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7yayb5e/5/). check it out

Edited: btw, to make the height:100% works, you need to add height:100% to all parent elements

Comment: Where did you get 344 and 104 from?

Comment: The size of the circle plus size of the rectable plus margin plus circle border (as you are not using box-sizing: border-box; )

Comment: Anyway my solution give the shapes a perfect centered both height and width... but you already marked as correct an answer with a very messy code that it doesn't even centered the elements right (not meaning to offend the poster at all, always glad to see people trying to help).

Comment: Sorry about that, I marked it before I saw yours. I can't quite get it to work on my actual project, it's not centered but too much to the left. I can't understand where those added margins come from (margin-top: 25px on one and margin-right: 40px on the other).

Comment: Margin right 40px is the distance betwwen the circle and the rectangle.

Comment: and as the circle has 100px height, and the rectangle is 50px... the rectangle has a margin top of 25px so both shapes are vertically centered

Comment: Very, very nice. My math was a little off, that's why I couldn't get it to work. Now it works perfectly! Although I feel bad about it I will change the best answer to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7yayb5e/4/)

CSS:

```
    body {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #666;
        height: 95%;
    }

    .background {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 30%;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .circle {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
        border: 2px solid #fafafa;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .rectangle {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure what's going on here.

Comment: Isn't this what you expect?

Comment: Sorry was a bit distracted when I looked at it. Now I've tested it on my real page and with a padding-bottom on the "rectangle" and some minor adjustments I think I can get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use left: 50%; and margin-left to give a certain offset from the center.
For example you want there to be 200 pixels between them.

```
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px; 
}
```

margin -200 comes from 100 for the width of the circle + 100, half of the 200px apart.

For the rectangle:

```
.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

This will centre the gap between them. If you want to centre the total you should subtract the difference in width between the two objects divided by 2 (25px) from the margins.

Comment: It is recommended not to use negative values in attributes like `margin`.

Comment: Sorry I can not get this to work. They still glide from each other.